# "layer-list" not working below api level 11

Tags: android

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#000000" >
            </solid>
            <size android:width="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="10dp">
        <color android:color="#F89D69" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I tried to set the View Background with two colors using "layer-list" in drawable.xml but the background is dispalying perfect for api level 11 onwards but is displaying only second color below that api level

Looking forward for Solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the second item as a shape like the first one